# Show/Hide jQuery does not work with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have a problem with following code:
I can't hide loading.
I've tried Mozilla,Chrome and it only works when you paste it to console.
Html of Loading on Start

```
<div class="loading" style="display: none">
```

After .show

```
<div class="loading" style="display: block;">
```

Ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/uzemnenie",
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("in ajax ", data.slice( 0, 100 ));
        $('.content').empty().html(data);
    }
});
```

Code on webpage

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
    $(".content").fadeOut( "slow", function() {
        $(".loading").show().css("display", "block");
    });
});

$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
    $(".loading").hide();
    $(".content").fadeIn("slow", function() {
        $('#show').fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

Works only when:

```
$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
                $(".loading").css("display", "none");
                $(".content").fadeIn("slow", function() {
                    $('#show').fadeIn("slow");
                });
            });
```

Weird part - Content is added too

```
                $( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
                $(".loading").hide(function(){
                $(".content").fadeIn("slow", function() {
                    $('#show').fadeIn("slow");
                });
                });
            });
```

And content is displayed right.
Thanks for answers.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Clean console - weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally it's very simple. The ajax request is faster done then you expected. Because of this the data you hide or show in ajaxStart isn't being processed completely while the request is already finished. So what you're doing in the ajaxStop function is being messed up by the end of show/hide functions you called previously in ajaxStart. This is the trap of asynchronous request. The easiest way around is to add a setTimeout().

You can see the working solution here [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LCeEJ/14/).

```
$(document).on({
  ajaxStart: function() { 
                    $(".content").fadeOut("slow");
                    $(".loading").show();
  },
  ajaxStop: function() {
      setTimeout(function() { 
                     $(".loading").fadeOut("slow");
                     $(".content").show("slow");     
                  }, 1500);                                        
  }    
});
```

Comment: Nothing i dont know why.

Comment: @VeeeneX Could you make a jsfiddle out of it? Then I'll take a closer look. Often I find my own issues during making the fiddle - this excludes many coinfluences that may happen with other resources and scripts.

Comment: @VeeeneX No problem - I updated your [__fiddle with ajax simulation__](http://jsfiddle.net/LCeEJ/12/) You forgot to call loader().

Comment: @VeeeneX  I guess that you took a look with FF or some other browser. I'm using chrome which ignored this tags. Usually you should enclose them in <ul> The updated fiddle should work.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't around last day. I'm glad if I could help you a bit. My last fiddle worked  - at least in Chrome. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LCeEJ/14/)

Comment: Thank you very much. Have a nice day and enjoy easter.

Answer (score 0):

Call this before the ajax call

```
$(".loading").show().css("display", "block");
```

And in success or error hide the loading.

```
$(".loading").hide().css("display", "none");
```

Comment: I can't because this code in running on index with some text...so i loading a new content to the page.